# Cannot relay thru gmail using mailx and ssmpt on buster pi0. Works on stretch/jessie pi3B,+ using heirloom-mailx

Tags: gmail, mailx, ssmtp

raspberry pi0w with buster, mailx [mail-utils} and ssmtp pointed to gmail relay at smtp.gmail.com:587 [using 2FA key]
pi0w syslog shows successful connection
executing "mailx --debug-level=3 ....." shows "sending body" and then "/usr/bin/sendmail[ssmtp]" exited with: 1  ->Nothing shows up on gmail sent tab

Using separate mail server [my own] with same setup to see maillog entries:
[syslog on pi02 shows]:
220  Dovecot ready
EHLO raspberrypi
250 pipelining"
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Begin TLS negotiation now"
SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES__256_GCM_SHA384"
EHLO raspberrypi

[/var/log/maillog on mailserver shows}:
submission-login: Remote connection closed user=<> ...Connection reset by peer

Something wrong.  I have seen user=<> before.  User auth doesn't get sent?
ALSO, I note that pi3B,3B+ use heirloom-mailx as "mailx" ---this not available buster [uses mailutils]  ---**mailx/ssmtp to gmail relay WORKS on pi3B, 3B+ with heirloom-mailx**
Cannot install heirloom-mailx on pi0w
Also tried msmtp instead of ssmtp.  Same exit of 1
Looks like I need heirloom-mailx!
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to msmtp which still doesn't work as used above
BUT:
googling around, msmtp on archwiki: to send mail with just msmtp
"cat msg |msmtp -a destemai@domain.com"
msmtp log complains it "cannot set X509 trust file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
? I -user pi- can read the .crt file, why do I need to write it as user pi? Is this what it means?

SO...... I commented out "tls_trust_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" in ~/.msmtrc  and it now works... Yeah! and I don't need mailx for my purposes.
Not sure what this means.......